# Is this wiring up to code?

Tags: wiring

I opened up a wall to renovate my kitchen and noticed something funny. The outlet on the right, which faced the kitchen, is fed with 12 gauge wire. Then there is a "jumper" line as shown, which is 14 gauge, connecting to the outlet on the left which faces the dining area.
Question 1: is this ok to leave?
Question 2: where would the wire be going from the outlet on the left back up through the ceiling? Could I assume it is feeding another outlet? I have to move both these vertical wires to remove this wall.[image]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the rating on the circuit breaker feeding this circuit?

Comment: Is the breaker for it 15 amps or 20 amps?  If 20 amp breaker, then need to replace 14g cable.  15 amp breaker 14g is okay, 12g is okay but more expensive to use when doing the wiring.

Comment: It's a 20 amp breaker. So would I assume that the line coming off the left side outlet is feeding another outlet elsewhere? Or vise versa?

Comment: What's your plan with this wall and the outlets?

Comment: I need to pull the two wires up through the holes in the top plate and feed them down along the column of 2x4s seen in the far right of this picture. The dining room outlet will stay in place, the kitchen outlet will move up to that column.

Comment: 20 amp breaker needs to have 12g cable.  If that jumper is the only 14g cable on the circuit, then just need to replace it with 12g.  Do not assume anything, check it over.  Can be other outlets/lights on both sides.

Comment: I always thought a kitchen had to be on its own 20 amp circuit with 12 ga wire?

Comment: I have been assuming that power comes into one outlet then out to the other outlet(both on same circuit).  It is possible that power comes in both sides if top and bottom outlets are separated( on two circuits).

Comment: It is suppose to be, but what people do is another thing.

Comment: Be sure you track down the other wire (up, to the left) before you do anything. As @crip659 noted, it's _possible_ that this goes to a different breaker that's not currently powered off. _Why_ someone would do that is, well, anyone's guess, but it's possible, and you don't want to be the guy that finds out, to your _shock_, that part of one of these boxes is still live.

Comment: What code are you asking about? We need to know where you live/where this wiring is located to know what your code is.

Comment: @BigLake I've seen varied enforcement of dining areas by inspectors, the NEC says "In the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all countertop outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for refrigeration equipment.".  There are exceptions for lighting and dedicated circuits

Answer (score 3):

After reading your comment on the wire size there are multiple code violations.

If there is 14 awg wire on a general purpose branch circuit the maximum breaker is 15 amps.

Also the nmb needs to be secured within 8-12” of the boxes. if clamps 12” is ok  but those appear to just be KO or knock out entries so a staple is required within 8”.

Today different sizes of nmb usually have different sheath colors; white for 14awg,  yellow for #12 and orange for 10awg. This was started as an inventory tracking but most manufacturers have adopted the colors/size
It is not mandated but started after Y2K and makes it easy to catch changes in wire sizes.

Black cable is used for both 6&8 awg not sure why they did not separate those sizes by color.

Answer (score 2):

Receptacles on the 2-or-more kitchen small appliance circuits can feed certain other areas, including the dining room. But they can't serve random other parts of the house. Plus there are requirements for receptacles on most walls by distance - I believe every 4' (so no more than 2' to a receptacle) in the kitchen, every 12' (so no more than 6' to a receptacle) in most other rooms. Generally speaking, with normal repairs and basic upgrades (tearing walls down may be a bit more than that) you can keep things compliant with older code but not compliant with newer code "as is" but anything new that you add has to meet current code. So a bunch of things to consider:

- If you don't already have at least 2 20A receptacle circuits dedicated to kitchen/dining areas, now is the time to add more circuits. You can have more than 2, but any that cover the kitchen need to **not** chain off to bedrooms, living room, etc.
- All 20A circuits need 12 AWG (or larger) wire throughout. That is not an "old code" vs. "new code" problem, so it needs to be fixed independent of any other changes. The catch is that since kitchen countertop/small appliance receptacles (new code) need to be 20A, you can't fix it by downgrading to 15A, you have to replace the 14 AWG with 12 AWG.
- If kitchen circuits feed other areas and you are opening up the walls anyway (as in the picture) then you should move the feed for the other areas to other circuits.
- Most kitchen receptacles must be GFCI protected. That can be at the breaker or at the first receptacle in each chain. May not be technically required if you are doing straight replacements, but **highly** recommended. Low cost. Easy to do. High level of life-safety protection.
- With certain exceptions, each counter area in the kitchen should have a receptacle on/in/next to it so that you can reach it within 2'. Exceptions are sinks, cooktops, etc.
- With certain exceptions, walls in most other rooms need a receptacle on each wall segment and every 12'. If the dining room receptacle in the picture is satisfying that requirement then you can't remove it because you can't make things worse. If it is not necessary to satisfy the requirement then you could remove it if that made your wiring task easier.

Comment: Likewise on kitchen circuits, only two receptacles need to be 20A, intended for stuff on countertops. They don't *all* need to be 20A, AFAIK. However, they also pretty much *all* need to be tamper-resistant these days, which a lot of people miss or outright skimp on due to extra cost.

Comment: @TylerH Most inspectors say otherwise.210.52(B)(1) " In the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and floor receptacle outlets..." There is an exception for dedicated circuits.

Comment: How do you conclude straight receptacle replacement may not technically require gfci protection in required locations? (I'm looking at 404.6(D)(3)).

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I stand corrected! I am not a code expert, and my understanding was that *in general* these changes were not needed for straight replacement. Looks like it changed in 2011.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease You are right.  Per the NEC this needs to be GFCI protected.  I think the point is: how many of us have replaced a receptacle without pulling a permit and bringing the entire branch circuit up to date with the current NEC?  Per the code, we should do that, but in practice we just replace the receptacle and move on.  I'm not an electrician, so this is what I would do *for my own house*.  If I were an electrician I would probably handle this differently.

Comment: @tnknepp You are 100% correct. Though I would suggest to any amateurs out there (like me) that any time you do a straight replacement in a kitchen or bathroom for some other reason, that you put in a GFCI if not already GFCI protected. When my electrician was doing work for me many years ago (before 2011), he didn't even ask - he just gave me the "you need this" line and he replaced the regular receptacles with GFCI (one in one bathroom was arguably needed - receptacle being replaced for other reasons, the other (protecting a circuit for two bathrooms) was absolutely unnecessary

Comment: (no change in that circuit at all) **but I did not complain because he was doing the right thing, even if not required by code at the time.**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I agree completely.  I'm sold on the GFCI and AFCI breakers and I'm slowly bringing my house into code compliance, but it's a long haul.  First thing I did in the kitchen when we bought the house (2 years ago) was replace old receptacles (from 60's) and put in a GFCI-protected circuit.  The benefit:cost ratio is extremely high; a no-brainer IMO.

Comment: AFCIs are a tougher sell, for a bunch of reasons. But GFCI for kitchen/bath is a no-brainer - full protection (unlike AFCI where full protection really requires in the panel (not always an option) or near the panel (usually extra work to install a box). But GFCI? First receptacle in the chain, straight replacement, done.